# Word Cloud in Elasticsearch 5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am able to get word cloud using old elasticsearch version using term aggregations. I want to get word cloud from **post content** in es5 and I am using below query.

```
"aggs": {
        "tagcloud": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "content.raw",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
```

I did mapping like this

```
"content": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is not coming as a word cloud as expected. It is grouping similar posts (whole post) and giving as a list given belown

```
"buckets": [
{
    "key" : "This car is awesome.",
    "doc_count" : 199
},
..
..
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The type `keyword` does pretty much the same as `string` with `not_analyzed` index mode. The whole string is indexed. And you can search only by exact value. 
In your case, I think, you need to use a field that is analyzed and tokenized, such as `content` field. However you need to make sure that the field's option `fielddata` is set to `true`. Otherwise server returns exception.
Therefore your mapping should look like

```
"content": {
   "fielddata" : true,
   "type": "text"
}
```

and aggregation

```
"aggs": {
    "tagcloud": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "content",
            "size": 10
        }
    }
}
```

As the result you should see something that looks like (it depends on what analyzer you choose)

```
"buckets": [
{
    "key" : "this",
    "doc_count" : 199
},
{
    "key" : "car",
    "doc_count" : 199
},
{
    "key" : "is",
    "doc_count" : 199
},
{
    "key" : "awesome",
    "doc_count" : 199
},
...
```

Comment: "fielddata" : true is very expensive thing as per es documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/fielddata.html. Is there any other way?

Comment: I am not aware of any, unfortunately.

Comment: @Mohammad Shahid The way that you can make it less expensive is by using fielddata_frequency_filter, so that in this way you don't have to store very frequent or infrequent words

Comment: Could you include a full query, please? So I can get an idea of what exactly to submit?